# Implementing a stack using a simple array, dynamic array and linked list

Tags: java, stack

I have implemented a stack using simple array, dynamic array and linked list. I am requesting a review of this code.

Interface for stack:

```
/**
 * Interface for stack
 */
public interface Stack<T> { 
public void push(final T data);
public T pop();
public boolean isStackEmpty();
public boolean isStackFull();
public T peek();
}
```

Implement stack using simple array:

```
/**
 * Inplement stack using array.
 */
public class Stack1<T> implements Stack<T>{ 
private int sizeOfStack;
private T stackArray[];
private static int tos; //top of stack

public Stack1(final int sizeOfStack) {
    tos = -1;
    stackArray = (T[])new Object[sizeOfStack];
    this.sizeOfStack = sizeOfStack;
}

/**
 * pushes item in the stack.
 * 
 * @param data
 */
public void push(final T data) {        
    if(isStackFull()) {
        throw new RuntimeException("stack is full cannot push");
    }
    stackArray[++tos] = data;       
}

/**
 * gets item from stack
 */
public T pop() {
    if(isStackEmpty()) {
        throw new RuntimeException("stack is empty");
    }
    return stackArray[tos--] ;
}

/** 
 * Checks if the stack is empty or not
 * 
 * @return boolean
 */
public boolean isStackEmpty() {     
    return (tos == -1);
}

/**
 * Check if the stack is full .
 * 
 * @return boolean
 */
public boolean isStackFull() {      
    return (tos == sizeOfStack - 1);
}

/**
 * Looks at the top element in the stack
 */
public T peek() {
    return stackArray[tos];
}
}
```

Implement stack using dynamic array:

```
/**
 * Dynamic array implementation.
 */
public class Stack2<T> implements Stack<T>{

private int tos ;
private int size;
private T[] array;

public Stack2(final int size) {
    tos = -1;
    this.size = size;
    array = (T[])new Object[size];
}

/**
 * pushes item in the stack.
 * 
 * @param data
 */
public void push(final T data) {            
    if(isStackFull()) {
        T[] array2 = (T[])new Object[size * 2];
        System.arraycopy(array, 0, array2, 0, array.length);
        array = array2;
    }
    array[++ tos] = data;
}

/**
 * gets item from the stack.
 */
public T pop() {
    return array[tos -- ];
}

/**
 * check if stack is empty
 */
public boolean isStackEmpty() {
    return (tos == -1);
}

/**
 * check if stack is full
 */
public boolean isStackFull() {
    return (tos == size - 1 );
}

/**
 * check the element from top of stack.
 */
public T peek() {
    return array[tos];
}
}
```

Implement stack using linked list:

```
/**
* Implement stack using LinkedList
*/
public class Stack3<T> implements Stack<T> {

Node<T> tos;

public Stack3() {
    tos = null;
}

public void push(final T data) {    
    Node<T> newNode = new Node<T>(data);
    newNode.setNext(tos);
    tos = newNode;
}

public T pop() {        
    if(tos != null) {
        final T item = tos.getData();
        tos = tos.getNext();
        return item;
    }
    return null;
}

public boolean isStackEmpty() {
    return (tos == null );
}

public boolean isStackFull() {
    return false;
}

public T peek() {
    return tos.getData();
}
}
```

Test cast for stack:

```
public class StackTest {

// test stack using array
@Test
public void test() {        
    Stack1<Integer> stack = new Stack1<Integer>(7); 
    stack.push(10);
    stack.push(20);
    stack.push(30);
    stack.push(40);
    stack.push(50);
    stack.push(5);
    stack.push(1);
    printStack(stack);
}

//test stack using dynamic array
@Test
public void test2() {       
    Stack2<Integer> stack = new Stack2<Integer>(7); 
    stack.push(10);
    stack.push(20);
    stack.push(30);
    stack.push(40);
    stack.push(50);
    stack.push(5);
    stack.push(1);
    stack.push(100);
    stack.push(200);
    stack.push(300);
    stack.push(400);
    stack.push(500);
    stack.push(600);
    stack.push(700);
    printStack(stack);
}

//test stack using linkedlist
@Test
public void test3() {       
    Stack3<Integer> stack = new Stack3<Integer>();  
    stack.push(10);
    stack.push(20);
    stack.push(30);
    stack.push(40);
    stack.push(50);
    stack.push(5);
    stack.push(1);
    stack.push(100);
    stack.push(200);
    stack.push(300);
    stack.push(400);
    stack.push(500);
    stack.push(600);
    stack.push(700);
    printStack(stack);
}

public void printStack(final Stack<Integer> stack) {
    while(!stack.isStackEmpty()) {
        System.out.println(stack.pop());
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### General

Your implementations are both a fixed size and a dynamic sizes stack that behave differently. Either choose to let them behave similarly (so add a fixed size), or change the interface.

### Tests

Your tests don't really test, they just print. You should add assertions. Also, test 'good path' and 'wrong path' (for example: pushing when the Stack is full)

### Naming

Please use proper names instead of short ones.

- `tos` is not readable, `topOfStack` is much clearer
- `isStackFull`. What does that mean? I would expect that you cannot add more elements if the stack is full.

### Magic values

You use a `-1` to indicate the stack is empty. I would add a constant with the name `TOP_OF_EMPTY_STACK` and document it

### Exceptions

You use `RuntimeException`. This is kind of a last resort then implementing an interface without `Exceptions`. You should use properly type exceptions like `StackFullException`

### Documentation

You add javadocs (good!). But you add them to the implementation, but not to the interface. Please add them to the interface and just `@See` in the implementation if nothing changes.